# How to get REST values of different type with Newtonsoft.JSON

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

This is a part of my REST response I get from the server (hopefully only the relevant parts for my question):

```
{
   "documents" : [
      {
         "fields" : [
            {
               "definition" : {
                  "href" : "https://www.../FAnZtVk-s5A",
                  "rel" : "field_definition",
                  "title" : "Title of first field"
               },
               "formatted" : "TheFormattedValue1",
               "value" : "Value1"
            },
            {
               "definition" : {
                  "href" : "https://www/yggc2yT69vY",
                  "rel" : "field_definition",
                  "title" : "Title of second field"
               },
               "formatted" : "TheFormattedValue2",
               "value" : "Value2"
            },
            {
               "definition" : {
                  "href" : "https://www/ptM7kdddz_M",
                  "rel" : "field_definition",
                  "title" : "Title of third field"
               },
               "formatted" : [
                  {
                     "icon" : "starred",
                     "text" : "Red"
                  }
               ],
               "value" : [
                  "-"
               ]
            },
```

The first and the second field "formatted" and "value" is of string type, the third one is an array of icon/text.

This is my .net class code:

```
Public Class clsRestDokumentenliste
    Public Property documents As List(Of Document)
    Public Property links As List(Of link)
    Public Property meta As Meta
End Class

Public Class Document
    Public Property fields As List(Of Field)
    Public Property forwarded As String
    Public Property invalid As String
End Class

Public Class Field
    Public Property definition As List(Of Definition)
    Public Property formatted As String
    Public Property value As String
End Class
```

When loading the data I get an error because the property "formatted" of the class "Field" is sometimes a string, sometimes another type of icon/text

```
Dokumente = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of clsRestDokumentenliste)(JSONstring)
```

I think the definition of Field in "List (of Field)" must be changed.
How do I have to define my classes to parse that?

Comment: `Public Property formatted As Object` might be better then, if you don't know the type in advance. Then when you use it, you'll have to try and cast it to the different possible types to work out what it actually is. But maybe a better solution, if you can, would be to improve the data sent by the server so it's not ambiguous in this way. By the way, your response is not REST, it's JSON. REST is just a set of architectural principles generally used to design web APIs. A RESTful service could theoretically return anything, but in your case it returns some data in JSON format.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, @ADyson. Object will work better, I understand